# I want a grid in android studio that will have 3 columns and 100 rows. Each cell should be a spinner and must retain selected value on scrolling

Tags: gridview, android-spinner

I want a gridview in android studio that will have 3 columns and 100 rows. Each cell should be a spinner and must retain selected value on scrolling.

Comment: Kindly help me with the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.